# Workbox cache is not served in offline

Tags: reactjs, webpack, workbox

im trying to precache all chuncks so that if there is a new build the user will be able to get the old chunks (until he will refresh the page)

So, I configured the `GenerateSW()` in the webpack configuration (with no configuration).

```
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW()
```

also tried with this configuration:

```
new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({
      skipWaiting: true,
      swDest: 'sw.js',
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: /^http:\/\/localhost:3000\/static\/.*$/,
          handler: 'NetworkFirst'
        }
      ]
    })
```

and registered the service worker like this:

```
  if ("serviceWorker" in navigator){
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js");
    })
```

Im able to see that the service worker indeed working and caching all the chunks, but when React is lazy loading one of them, I'm getting a server error (I tried to just shut down the server). instead of getting the cached chunk.

What am I doing wrong? thanks.
}

Comment: What is the server error? What is the configuration passed to `GenerateSW`?

Comment: Hey, @morganney. no configuration. i will update the post with the code. and the error is a normal error when the server is offline (I just checked the `offline` option in the network tab)